Differences between hafs and warsh in certain verses
Salam, I’ve recently been looking at the differences between hafs and warsh variants and can understand the difference between most of them. However, I looked at a website recently which said that in Quran 66:12, in the hafs version it says “his books” while in the warsh version it says “his book.” Does this not change the meaning in the verse? Also, there are differences regarding singular and plural in other places as well, so I was wondering if that changes the meaning? Jazakallah Khair

Recitations can have different meanings, but they are complementary and non-contradictory.
Allah says in verse 66:12:

And [the example of] Mary, the daughter of 'Imran, who guarded her chastity, so We blew into [her garment] through Our angel, and she believed in the words of her Lord and His scriptures/scripture and was of the devoutly obedient.

It is like how a Muslim would say "I believe in the book of Allah" intending specifically the Quran and can also say "I believe in the books of Allah" intending the different books sent to the prophets including but not limited to the Quran.
The same can apply to Maryam (AS), and in her case, the singular book would most likely refer to the Torah of Musa (AS).

A singular word can be used to refer to its genus, just like a plural is used to refer to its genus. Hence they are equivalent. The meaning is that she believed in the revelations sent by Allah, and this can include what was sent to Abraham, Moses, David, Jesus عليهم السلام أجمعين .
Some other examples:



ولقد خلقنا الإنسان ونعلم ما توسوس به نفسه ونحن أقرب إليه من حبل الوريد
And We have already created man and know what his soul whispers to him, and We are closer to him than [his] jugular vein
— Quran 50:16

The word إنسان (man) is singular but here it means the genus of humans and hence is equivalent to 'men'.



وجاء ربك والملك صفا صفا
And your Lord has come and the angel, rank upon rank,
— Quran 89:22

The word الملك (angel) is singular but here it is used to depict the genus and hence is equivalent to 'angels'.


Also note that if she believed in one book (Gospel) then she automatically believed in others, since the books themselves require belief in past and future revelations.
Ref:

والكتاب يراد به الجنس
— Tafsir al-Qurtubi

